# Validate $Path Parameter Exists & Is Folder - Issue with Spaces

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to validate a PowerShell script path parameter. I want to check that it exists and that it is a folder. Here's my parameter setup/validation script:

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [ValidateScript({
    if( -Not ($_ | Test-Path) ){ throw 'Folder does not exist.' }
    if( -Not ($_ | Test-Path -PathType Container) ){ throw 'The Path parameter must be a folder. File paths are not allowed.' }
    return $true
  })]
  [String]$Path
)
```

**Usage:** `.\script.ps1 -Path "C:\Test Path With Space"`

When running this on a path that contains a space, it fails validation with: `Folder does not exist.`

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a better way to approach getting a valid folder path?

**Note:** I chose to use a `String` parameter instead of `System.IO.FileInfo` so that I could ensure there was a trailing `\` in the path.

Comment: Are you quoting the path you're passing as parameter when it has spaces?

Comment: Yes. I'll add example usage.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your function, and your sample call should preserve the spaces in the path correctly. Based on the information in your question, the only explanation is that path `"C:\Test Path With Space"` doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for confirming. The folder does exist. The detail I failed to share is that I'm deploying this script from an RMM. It must be handling the parameter in a way that breaks the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can explain your script validation failing is that you're not quoting the path with spaces, an easy way of testing this using `Write-Host $_` on your [ValidateScript attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validatescript-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2):

- Given `script.ps1`:

```
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateScript({ Write-Host $_; $true })]
  [String]$Path
)
```

Testing the parameter without quotes:

```sh
PS /> ./script.ps1 /path/with spaces

/path/with # => This is Write-Host $_
script2.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'spaces'.
```

As you can see, in PowerShell, if you want to bound an argument with a parameter, and said argument (*string*) **has spaces**, [the value must be enclosed in quotation marks, or the spaces must be preceded by the escape character (`` ` ``)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#parameter-type).

```sh
PS /> ./script.ps1 '/path/with spaces' 
/path/with spaces

PS /> ./script.ps1 /path/with` spaces
/path/with spaces
```

As for, how you can improve the path validation, what you're doing seems fine. You could swap the order of the condition so it's more straight forward:

```
param(
  [ValidateScript({ 
      if(Test-Path $_ -PathType Container) {
          return $true
      }
      elseif(Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) {
          throw 'The Path parameter must be a folder. File paths are not allowed.'
      }
      throw 'Invalid File Path'
  })]
  [string]$Path
)
```